# How do I use a blender object as a engine in my flutter app?

Tags: python, flutter, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, blender

I made a character in blender and rigged it. I am interested in importing that file into my flutter app and then feeding it chatbot commands with text to speech like: "flutterTts.speak("Hello how are you?") or from a json file with google tts. How do I do this? Do I need to use opengl es with python and then have a python api call from the flutter app? How do I even do that? Would really appreciate help/pointing me in the right direction--thanks!

Comment: I doubt that this is possible at all using Flutter natively. If anything, it might be achievable using platform views.

Comment: Use `flutter_3d_obj` for 3D Objects.

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan tried that but it doesn't work for animations which is what is needed

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot what do you mean by platform views? Could I make a python api and then have an get request?